# What happens after death according to Vedic samhitas?

Tags: vedas, death, samhita

I could not find references to rebirth in Vedic samhitas i.e.,  Rig Veda, Sama Veda, Yajur veda and Atharva veda.

I would like to know what happens after death according to Vedic samhitas (Rig Veda, Sama Veda, Yajur veda or Atharva veda).

I heard that the Rig Veda describes how after death a man's eyes get merged in sun, breath in air, ashes in plants, but is this true? If not, then what exactly happens after death according to Vedic samhitas (Rig Veda, Sama veda, Yajur veda or Atharva veda)?

Comment: Is this - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21502/is-reincarnation-or-rebirth-mentioned-in-the-vedas-samhitas and the above same?

Comment: @swift pushkar it's simiiar but I want to know what is concept of death after Vedic samhitas like a guy was saying a according to Vedic samhitas after death a man's eyes gets merged in sun,breath in air etc

Answer (score 3):

This is explained in *RV* mandala X hymn 56. It is either a horse or a son of Bṛhaduktha named Vajin who died recently.

[image]

> इदं त एकं पर ऊ त एकं तर्तीयेन जयोतिषा संविशस्व | idaṃ ta ekaṃ para ū
>   ta ekaṃ tṛtīyena jyotiṣā saṃviśasva
>
> संवेशने तन्वश्चारुरेधि परियो देवानाम्परमे जनित्रे || saṃveśane
>   tanvaścāruredhi priyo devānāmparame janitre ||

First two verse describes how body would divide into various constituents and unities with Agni, Vayu, and light. Also, consciousness unites with the Sun.

Then in next verse, the journey of the dead into some unknown world is described followed by how dead person unites with his old body and their meeting the with *pitrs* who have achieved godhood after death.

The hymn:

> 1 HERE is one light for thee, another yonder: enter the third and he therewith united.Uniting with a body be thou welcome, dear to the Gods
>   in their sublimest birthplace.
>
> 2 Bearing thy body, Vajin, may thy body afford us blessing and thyself
>   protection.Unswerving, stablish as it were in heaven thine own light
>   as the mighty God's supporter.
>
> 3 Strong Steed art thou: go to the yearning Maidens with vigour,
>   happily go to heaven and praises: Fly happily to the Gods with easy
>   passage, according to the first and faithful statutes.
>
> 4 Part of their grandeur have the Fathers also gained: the Gods have
>   seated mental power in them as Gods.They have embraced within
>   themselves all energies, which, issuing forth, again into their bodies
>   pass.
>
> 5 They strode through all the region with victorious might,
>   establishing the old immeasurable laws.They compassed in their bodies
>   all existing things, and streamed forth offipring in many successive
>   forms.
>
> 6 In two ways have the sons established in his place the Asura who
>   finds the light, by the third act,As fathers, they have set their
>   heritage on earth, their offspring, as a thread continuously spun out.
>
> 7 As in a ship through billows, so through regions of air, with
>   blessings, through toils and troubles, Hath Bṛhaduktha brought his
>   seed with glory, and placed it here and in the realms beyond us.

Comment: it is called hymn 56 not verse,verses are contained inside the hymns so the correct way of telling is book 10 hymn 56.btw can you provide English translation of hymn 56 of mandal 10?

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda there is a slight difference in Hindi translation and English translation of the hymn. I encourage you to read a summary from below book https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=1-PRAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA1466&dq=afterdeath+rigveda&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=afterdeath%20rigveda&f=false

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda The above is considered as a best translation so far. You may download it from here. https://www.academia.edu/30160889/Stephanie_W._Jamison_Joel_P._Brereton_The_Rigveda_3_Volume_Set_-_2014_.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is no mention of rebirth but there is mention of liberation- moksha throughout samhitas.

Rig Veda in 7.59.12 tells Shiva [Rudra] is the God who grants eternal Mokshya. Rishi Vasistha is the Seer and Rudra is the devta and it invokes the Three Eyed One.

> The verse is:
>
> त्र्यम्बकं यजामहे सुगन्धिं पुष्टिवर्धनम् उर्वारुकमिव
>   बन्धनान्मृत्योर्मुक्षीय माऽमृतात् ।।
>
> tryambakaṃ yajāmahe sugandhiṃ pushtivardhanam urvārukamiva
>   bandhanānmṛmrityor mokshiye maamritat ।।
>
> The simple meaning of verse is:
>
> We worship the Three-eyed Lord who is fragrant and who nourishes and
>   nurtures all beings. As is the ripened cucumber freed from its bondage
>   (to the creeper), may He liberate us from death for the sake of
>   immortality.

Purusha sukta and Narayana sukta also say that one who knows Purusha leaves death behind and becomes immortal.

If Vedic samhitas accept liberation they'll accept rebirth too.